# Batch command to check DotNet 4.5.2 installed check?

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, command-line, cmd

my dotnet c# application can be run only on **DotNet 4.5.2** platform only. How can i check it using batch command? I found the following command for DotNet 4.5 check. How can i change it for **DotNet 4.5.2**?

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5" 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo .NET Framework 4.5 is NOT installed
) else (
    echo .NET Framework 4.5 is installed
)
```

Comment: I guess this is what you want [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15227828/4422347)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the "same" to check for other versions. For you this would be:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo .NET Framework 4.5.2 is NOT installed
) else (
    echo .NET Framework 4.5.2 is installed
)
```